# Calcaluting mass with density different integral methods different results?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, stars, integration

I need to calculate the following mass with given density.

I know that the density is : $p(r)=p_{0}\frac{r}{R}$.

The problem is that in the book they ask to calculate the mass yet in two different exercises which has the density shown above they ask to calculate the mass but they are using different integral method as shown below which lead to different results.

- The first question ask to calculate the mass of a cylindrical barrel in this question the book uses the first method shown below
- The second question ask to calculate a amass of a star and uses the second method.

When I use:

First method:

Assume $L$ is the height of the barrel

$$\iiint \limits_{0\ 0\ 0}^{L \ 2\pi R}(r,\theta,z)\, dr\,d\theta\,dz=\iiint \limits_{0\ 0\ 0}^{L \ 2\pi R}p(r)dv=\iiint \limits_{0\ 0\ 0}^{L \ 2\pi R}p(r)*rdr\,d\theta\,dz=\iiint \limits_{0\ 0\ 0}^{L \ 2\pi R}p_{0}\frac{r^2}{R}\, dr\,d\theta\,dz=..=\frac{2 \pi LRp_{0}}{3}$$

and on the other hand :

Second method:

$$\iiint \limits_{0\ 0\ 0}^{\pi \ 2\pi R}(r,\theta,\phi)\, dr\,d\theta\,dz=p(r)dv=\iiint \limits_{0\ 0\ 0}^{\pi \ 2\pi R}p(r)*r^2*sin(\theta)dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=\iiint \limits_{0\ 0\ 0}^{\pi \ 2\pi R}p_{0}\frac{r}{R}*r^2*sin(\theta)=..=p_{0}*\pi*R^3$$

How could I know which integral method to use? or both of them are correct?

Comment: Calculating geometric properties of objects with different kinds of symmetry (in your case one is cylindrical and the other is spherical) should obviously provide you different results. The "methods" you used are the same, what changed was the volume form.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please note that the Roman letter $p$ is different from the Greek letter $\rho$.

Comment: What is your background regarding multiple integrals? Both exercises are just simple applications of this branch of calculus, but it can obviously be confusing if you have never seen these things before.

Answer (score 0):

Use one for spherical objects, the other for cylindrical objects.  I believe that is the simple answer you are looking for.